# ¿Como puedo solucionar este tipo de error al testear?

Tags: java, oracle, eclipse, while

Al ejecutar en la consola pasa que me bota un error de "next" que esta alojado en el "while"

> java.sql.SQLException: No se puede realizar la recuperación en una
>   sentencia PLSQL: next     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:254)
>     at upeu.juan.daoimp.registroimp.read(registroimp.java:45)

```
public registro read(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        registro f = new registro();

        try {
            c = x.prepareCall("{Call pro_reg (?,?,?,?)}");
            c.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            c.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            c.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            c.setInt(4,id);
            r=c.executeQuery();
            while (r.next()){
                f.setId(r.getInt("cod_bus"));
                f.setPlacas(r.getString("placa_bus"));
                f.setViajes(r.getInt("count(*)"));
            }


        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return f;
```

Comment: Yo diría que el error está en pro_reg.

Comment: Dependiendo de lo que devuelva executeQuery podrás llamar a la función next, ¿no? ¿Qué te devuelve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [sintaxis de escape de JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefjdbc1020262.html) las palabras claves son **sensible a las mayúsculas y minúsculas**. Y  como devuelves un solo resultado acorde al id, deberías usar execute() solamente.

*Nota:* ver comentarios para entender el paso a paso.

### read(int id):

```
        // obtener conexión a base de datos oracle
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:caspian";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        // preparar CallableStatement
        String pro_reg = "{ call pro_reg(?, ?, ?, ?) }";
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(pro_reg);
        // definir parametro de entrada 
        cs.setInt(4,id);

        // Registrar parametros de salir
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

        // ejecutar procedimiento
        cs.execute();

        Registro f = new Registro(); //clase debería estar capitalizada
        //obtienes parametros y los seteas a tu registro
        f.setId(cs.getInt("cod_bus"));
        f.setPlacas(cs.getString("placa_bus"));
        f.setViajes(cs.getInt("count(*)"));


        return f;
```